# Presence Of an Another Universe

Tags: cosmology, universe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Experimental evidence for parallel universes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14255/experimental-evidence-for-parallel-universes)

Is there an universe similar to ours somewhere else, I mean I had heard from Einsteins theories that,actually when I am typing this question here, there is an another world somewhere else where I would be typing this question simultaneously. Is this true, if so any evidences.